# Navbar align items in a row

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get my navbar items to align rather than stack. I switched from bootstrap 3 to 4 (beta 2) and for some reason it doesn't nicely align anymore but remains stacked. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>index__</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>




<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



    <nav class="navbar fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <span class="pull-left">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="img/gyn_sm.png" alt="">
            </a>
            </span>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li>one</li>
                <li>two</li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </nav>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this u[pdated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8qxax7p/) to get the answer. Your `.navbar-nav` gets `display: flex;`, but not its direction. Adding this to the CSS as:

```
.navbar-nav {
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

will fix it. Read more about `flex-direction` [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).

Comment: Hey thanks that's almost perfect. How do I make sure the items don't stick together? I tried adding <p> tags but that doesn't seem to make the trick?

Comment: @S.L. I updated the JSFiddle, added `padding` to the `li` of the menu items. (See the CSS part)